# collapse / compress vector of repeated elements to max k-repeated

Tags: r

Is there a more efficient way than function below based on `rle` to compress/collapse a vector, of lets's say strings, into max k-repeated. Example input and desired outputs given below, .

Input

```
foov <- rep(c("a", "b", "a"), c(5, 3, 2))
```

For k = 2, desired output would be:

```
"a" "a" "b" "b" "a" "a"
```

And for k = 3, desired output would be:

```
"a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "a" "a"
```

At the moment I am using `rle` as follows to achieve this:

```
collapseRLE <- function(v, k) {
  vrle <- rle(v)
  vrle$lengths[vrle$lengths > k] <- k
  ret <- rep(vrle$values, vrle$lengths)
  return(invisible(ret))
}
foov <- rep(c("a", "b", "a"), c(5, 3, 2))
print(collapseRLE(foov, 2))
```

Comment: Seems a pretty good way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table`.  Based on the grouping by `rleid` on the vector, we subset from the index provided the sequence of 'k' and extract the columns as a vector (`$V1`)

```
library(data.table)
f1 <- function(k, vec) data.table(vec)[, vec[seq_len(pmin(k, .N))], rleid(vec)]$V1
f1(2, foov)
#[1] "a" "a" "b" "b" "a" "a"
f1(3, foov)
#[1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "a" "a"
```